# Place Header and Footer in android

Tags: android-layout, android

I wanted to place Header and footer on the TabHost Im trying but thats not showing any change in UI heres my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button01"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TabWidget>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost></RelativeLayout>
```

Please Help me I want to place 2 buttons and title on Header and 4 buttons on footer

Thank you

Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

you need to use layout above and layout below properties also!!

Comment: Can you please explain me in brief

Comment: you have used relativelayout but are you using that properly!! We use relativelayout to set views with reference to other views.       Now here when you are adding some views inside relativelayout those child views have properties like layout above and layout below. YOU NEED TO SET THOSE.